# If/else in FormatJS / React-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

Is it possible to have an if/else in a FormatJS message?

Example

I have a boolean variable `isDay` that should determine what message is shown. When `true` I want to show the wording "Day" and when `false` I want to show `Night`.

```
// message string
message = "Day";

// React component
<FormattedMessage
 id="message"
 values={{isDay: true}}
/>
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
message = "{if isDay}Day{else}Night{endif}";
```

I know the above is not the actual syntax, but wondering if something like this is possible with [FormatJS](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components/#formattedmessage)?

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution using the ICU Message [select](https://support.crowdin.com/icu-message-syntax/#select) syntax.

```
message = "{isDay, select, true {Day} other {Night}}";
```

Comment: It seems that `other` is required. https://formatjs.io/docs/core-concepts/icu-syntax/#select-format